# Obtaining documents of Cuthbert and Baird families

Tags: surnames, vital-records, scotland, documents

The names of my Cuthberts were, George, James, John, Lewis and others of the family.  The specific ones that came to Savannah, GA., USA are James, John, Lewis.

John Cuthbert came in the Prince of Wales", on 11 August 1739.  I believe he or his son, James had a sister, Rachel who married Simon Fraser. I do know James Cuthbert was a physician in GA and he died before 1783 in Savannah, GA. I have copies of wills of John A Cuthbert, his sister Ann, brother Lewis, and others. His father John had a plantation also in Beaufort, SC along with others in GA.  In Scotland, according to Peerage books, the Cuthberts owned or was chartered Drakies and or Castle Hill in Inverness.

The Baird families also lived in some of the same castles, included Newbyth,Auchmedden,(Aberdeenshire).  This was copied from a descendant of the Bairds, http://aroundbritainnoplane.blogspot.com/2007/07/looking-for-baird-castle.html:

> DOMINUS FECIT
>
> Erected to the memory of William Baird, of Auchmedden, Esq, chief of
>   that ancient name. His participation in the rising of 1745 occasioned
>   tohim and his descendants the loss of the family estates, he died at
>   Aberdeen 1777 aged 76. And of his wife Anne Duff, sister of William
>   Earl of Fife, who died 1773, aged 68. And also of Henrietta their
>   daughter, spouse of Francis Fraser Esquire of Findrack, who died 18
>   July 1801.

Can anyone tell me where I might obtain any documentation of these people?

I am just trying to prove my Cuthberts in Ga and SC were from Scotland and married into these families, along with so many other known Scottish surnames I have.

Comment: I am a direct descendent of Dr James Cuthbert of Iverness, Scotland. My great great great grandfather lived in the Castle in Beaufort. His wife, Ophelia Lasak, portrait hangs in our family home. I have a lot of family information on the Cuthberts and Barnwells of Beaufort, SC. My family was married to several barnwells. I am not sure if this is still an active forum but if you have any questions, I would love to help answer!

Comment: Does anyone know how to contact the poster @PolyGeo  This post was a year ago, and the link does not work to email. I have family relations with both Cuthberts and Bairds. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you, Linda Snow Davis.  my email address is Ldsed@aol.com

Comment: Sorry @LindaDavis the only way to contact the commenter will be if they include their email in their profile. Including an email address in comment like you have done may get their attention but comments are temporary.